The bonding configuration information is automatically deleted after the server reboots
I am setting bonding at 22.04.5.
Network communication is very good after setup is completed.
However, when I reboot the server, the bonding information I set disappears.
Did I set anything wrong? I wonder.
The installer is a package.
root@test:~# dpkg -l |grep ifenslave
ii  ifenslave                              2.10ubuntu3                             all          configure network interfaces for parallel routing (bonding)
root@test:~# dpkg -l |grep net-tool
ii  net-tools                              1.60+git20181103.0eebece-1ubuntu5       amd64        NET-3 networking toolkit
root@test:~# dpkg -l |grep ifupdown
ii  ifupdown                               0.8.36+nmu1ubuntu3.1                    amd64        high level tools to configure network interfaces
It's mod.
root@test:~# lsmod |grep bonding
bonding               200704  0
tls                   114688  1 bonding
Bonding setting value.
root@test:~# cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
network configuration capabilities, write a file
/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
network: {config: disabled}
network:
ethernets:
enp86s0f0np0:
dhcp4: no
enp153s0f0np0:
dhcp4: no
bonds:
bond0:
addresses: [10.xx.xxx.xx/24]
routes:
- to: default
via: 10.xx.xxx.254
nameservers:
addresses: [10.xx.xxx.xx, 10.xx.xxx.xx]
interfaces:
- enp86s0f0np0
- enp153s0f0np0
parameters:
mode: active-backup
mii-monitor-interval: 100
down-delay: 0
up-delay: 0
primary: enp86s0f0np0
version: 2
Proc bonding information.
root@test:~# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v5.15.0-119-generic
Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)
Primary Slave: enp86s0f0np0 (primary_reselect always)
Currently Active Slave: enp86s0f0np0
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0
Peer Notification Delay (ms): 0
Slave Interface: enp86s0f0np0
MII Status: up
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 1
Permanent HW addr: 6c:92:cf:3e:xx:xx
Slave queue ID: 0
Slave Interface: enp153s0f0np0
MII Status: up
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 1
Permanent HW addr: 6c:92:cf:3f:xx:xx
Slave queue ID: 0
I'd appreciate it if you could give me an answer.

network:
ethernets:
enp86s0f0np0:
dhcp4: no
enp153s0f0np0:
dhcp4: no
bonds:
bond0:
addresses: [10.xx.xxx.xx/24]
routes:
- to: default
via: 10.xx.xxx.254
nameservers:
addresses: [10.xx.xxx.xx, 10.xx.xxx.xx]
interfaces:
- enp86s0f0np0
- enp153s0f0np0
parameters:
mode: active-backup
mii-monitor-interval: 100
down-delay: 0
up-delay: 0
primary: enp86s0f0np0
version: 2
